# How to display Stack object in this case?

Tags: c#

I am practicing ArrayList, Stack collection with this blow

```
namespace Practice
{
    public class Student
    {
        public static Stack Grades = new Stack();
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Student(string firstname, string lastname)
        {
            this.FirstName = firstname;
            this.LastName = lastname;
        }

        public void grades(params int[] score)
        {
            Grades.Push(score);
        }       
    }
}

namespace Practice
{
    class Program
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        ArrayList StuArray = new ArrayList();

        Student stu1 = new Student("Super", "Geek");
        Student stu2 = new Student("Jack", "Nerd");
        Student stu3 = new Student("kim", "meh");

        stu1.grades(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
        stu2.grades(29, 24, 54, 75, 32);
        stu3.grades(21, 23, 55, 99, 24);

        StuArray.Add(stu1);
        StuArray.Add(stu2);
        StuArray.Add(stu3);

        foreach (Student student in StuArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The student First Name is {student.FirstName} and Last Name is {student.LastName}");                    
        }
    }
}
```

}

even though I store the data in Grades stack through Student object with grades method in the grades, I've kept failing to display the stack in this case.

I thought

```
foreach ( object a in stu1.grades)
{ 
  Console.WriteLine($"the grades of each student is {a}");
}
```

or something but I was wrong.

is there anybody to give me any hints for this?

Thank you~!

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList` vs `Stack<T>` or `List<T>`?

Comment: What do you actually get in the console?

Comment: Is their a special reason for the _`static`_ in `public static Stack Grades = new Stack();` because with _`static`_ all students will have all grades instead of their own stack of grades. I guess you are mixing _`readonly`_ with _`static`_

Comment: I think I just use "static" to use Student.Grades like foreach ( object obj in Student.Grades) haha.  I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is you are adding the whole param collection to the first item of the stack, instead of the individual items.

The following code should work.

```
public void grades(params int[] score)
{
    foreach(var grade in score)
    {
        Grades.Push(score);
    }
}
```